# IF formula for Multiple Rows

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create an if formula to look at an entire column and if it matches a number of rows then add the value_if_true. So I want to look at the entire column C to see if there is a match to column B rows 2-20 then input the true value but leave blank if false. When I use the following formula I'm just getting a error, the array value cannot be found. How do I need to adjust this or is this even the right formula?

```
=IF(C:C=B2:B20,"Yes",)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that we can't see your spreadsheet. We don't know you data, data types, layout, locale, etc. So it would be difficult to impossible to guess at the best approach. Consider sharing a link to the spreadsheet (or to a copy of it).

Comment: Thanks. here is a link to the spreadsheet. I'm basically trying to get where if the neighbourhhood number(Column C) matches a number in the number list in column H that it inputs the new ward name in column B
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qQTFBFxPpfXWGErw9RcTZpGCNndas4B-CVUdVt_uDQc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Please see my newly added sheet ("Erik Help"). The formula is in B1:

`=ArrayFormula({"New Ward Name";IF(C2:C="",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2:C,H:H,1,FALSE)))})`

This formula will produce the header text (which you can change *within the formula* as you like) and all results for all columns. If a match is found between Col C and Col H, Col C will be returned. If no match is found or the row is otherwise blank, null ("blank") will be returned.